# How to make an exception for a directory in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a `VirtualHost` serving `http://wiki.example.com` ([dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/start)):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName wiki.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/dokuwiki

# some access restrictions on directories
</virtualHost>
```

How should I configure my server so that the contents of `/var/www/other` are served by the URL `http://wiki.example.com/other`? In the setup above dokuwiki handles the URL though an internal rewrite mechanism and makes it pointing to an new (empty) page handled by its engine.

I realize that I could create a new `VirtualHost` but this is not an immediate option (I have to keep the hostname `wiki.example.com`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) command:

```
Alias /other /var/www/other
```